# SQLite syntax error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am writing an app. I get this error when my app crashes:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "@kiit": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from LoginMaster where UserID = 1505293@kiit.ac.in and Password = harshit999;`

When I enter the `UserID` and `Password` which I have already successfully inserted into the table, that's when I get the error:

```
package com.harshit.csdp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText kiitmail, pass;
    private Spinner spn;
    private TextInputLayout inputKiitMail;
    SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
    Button register, login;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        sqldb = openOrCreateDatabase("xyza", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        final String adminEmail = "admin@kiit.ac.in";
        final String adminPass = "admin123";
        final String adminStatus = "Administrator" ;



        boolean firstRun = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstRun", true);
        if(firstRun){
            getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).commit();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First Run Detected.\nDatabase, tables and Administrator account created.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            sqldb.execSQL("Create table LoginMaster(UserID varchar, Password varchar,Status varchar)");
            sqldb.execSQL("insert into LoginMaster values('"+adminEmail+"','"+adminPass+"','"+adminStatus+"')");

            sqldb.execSQL("Create table StudentMaster(UserID varchar, RollNo varchar,Batch varchar, Branch varchar, Degree varchar, JoiningYear varchar)");
            sqldb.execSQL("Create table FacultyMaster(UserID varchar, Degree varchar, JoiningYear varchar)");
            sqldb.execSQL("Create table StudentPersonalMaster(UserID varchar, Name varchar, DOB varchar, Gender varchar, Address varchar, MobNumber varchar)");
            sqldb.execSQL("Create table FacultyPersonalMaster(UserID varchar, Name varchar, DOB varchar, Gender varchar, MobNumber varchar)");
            sqldb.execSQL("Create table StudentAcademicMaster(UserID varchar, AcademicAchievement varchar,Sports varchar, Cultural varchar, Others varchar, HighSchool varchar)");
            sqldb.execSQL("Create table StudentTechnicalMaster(UserID varchar, PLanguage varchar,Database varchar, OS varchar, Software varchar, OtherSkill varchar, IndustryExperience varchar, AcademicProject varchar)");
            sqldb.execSQL("Create table NoticeMaster(UserID varchar, Title varchar,Content varchar, Type varchar, Date varchar)");
        }

        kiitmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        spn  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(spn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(adminStatus)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AdminPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(verifyLogin()&&spn.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Student")){
                    String km = kiitmail.getText().toString();
                    Intent studentPage = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, StudentPage.class);
                    studentPage.putExtra("uid",km);
                    startActivity(studentPage);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fuck you",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });


        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome.ttf" );
        TextView textView7 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        TextView textView8 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        textView7.setTypeface(font);
        textView8.setTypeface(font);

        register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),InitialRegistrationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
    public boolean verifyLogin(){
        String checkMailID = kiitmail.getText().toString();
        String checkPassword = pass.getText().toString();
        Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery("Select * from LoginMaster where UserID = "+checkMailID+" and Password = "+checkPassword+";", null);
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

How do I fix this error? Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you might be missing the `'` around your UserID and Password values

Comment: Change your query to this and try 
`Select * from LoginMaster where UserID = '"+checkMailID+"' and Password = '"+checkPassword+"' ;` Use `'` when you're passing strings.

Comment: **Need help fast** ... !!

Answer (score 1):

Perform your query this way:

```
Cursor cursor = sqldb.rawQuery("Select * from LoginMaster where UserID = \""+checkMailID+"\" and Password = \""+checkPassword+"\";", null);
```

You have to quote your query parameters. Furthermore your code is vulnerable for SQL-Injection. Do not use a raw query, but the query api: [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow)